# Pixi.JS Dashed (or dotted) Bezier Curve

Tags: svg, canvas, pixi.js

I'm working on a network graph and would like to use bezier curves to represent multiple edges between and two given nodes.

I would like to animated a dashed line to represent this edge.

There are [quite](https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs/issues/1333#issuecomment-379000150) [a](https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs/issues/1333#issuecomment-424324927) [few](https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs/issues/1333#issuecomment-293302823) examples and conversations floating around regarding dashed *lines* but not dashed *curves*.

I'm very new to Pixi.JS and am struggling to even find which direction to go to explore figuring out this topic.

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction and give a few examples of dashed curves in Pixi.JS

Comment: There is dashed line feature in "PixiJS Smooth Graphics" plugin: https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs/issues/7897#issuecomment-948493891 . This plugin is created by one of Pixi.js authors ( https://github.com/ivanpopelyshev )

Comment: That definitely makes dashed bezier curves easier to implement. I wonder if you have an idea what I could do to animate them? I ended up stealing some code from [bezier.js](https://github.com/Pomax/bezierjs) to get points for sections along a bezier curve. I believe animating those might do it, but need to find the best way to offset each segment

Comment: "I wonder if you have an idea what I could do to animate them?" - unfortunately no, but i suggest to also post in "discussions" in Pixi.js github repo: https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs/discussions . Also would be good if you describe more about what it means "to animate" - and show some example of such "animation" with simple straight line etc.

Comment: @domis86 thank you, I’ll plug away at this a bit more to see if I can answer my own question. If I fail, I will post in that thread

Comment: @domis86 You should put your comment as an answer, it was exactly what I needed!